# JOINS instead of Sub-SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

Is it true that SUBSELECTs are less performant than JOINs?

I got this query

```
SELECT   categories_id,
         products_id
FROM     products_to_categories a
WHERE    date_added = (
  SELECT MIN(date_added)
  FROM   products_to_categories b
  WHERE a.products_id = b.products_id
)
AND      categories_id != 0
GROUP BY products_id
```

and would like to change it into a query with JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.products_id,
         b.MinDate
FROM     products_to_categories a
JOIN     (SELECT b.products_id,
            MIN(b.date_added) AS MinDate
          FROM products_to_categories b
          GROUP BY b.products_id ) AS B
  ON     a.products_id = b.products_id
 AND     a.date_added = b.MinDate
WHERE    a.categories_id != 0
```

Comment: This is what I tried before but I got this error _#1052 - Column 'categories_id' in field list is ambiguous_

Comment: i just modified, the SELECT columns need a prefix of a.

Comment: Now I get _#1111 - Invalid use of group function_

Comment: is this some MySQL issue?  My SQL is for SQLSERVER

Comment: You cannot have an aggregate function in the WHERE clause

Comment: This is a integrated SQL-Server in MAMP

Comment: I completely re-wrote, joing to a DERIVED table now...  I added the MinDate to the main resultset if you wanted it but the main SELECT no longer requires a GROUP BY

Comment: try the join now, this will only show records from A for that MinDate

Comment: It gives me more results than the subselect. Very strange

Comment: Maybe it would be better I could send you the whole table, then you will see that the JOIN query gets two results for the products_id = 28 and it can only be one result

Comment: i get it... hold on, we do have to group the main SELECT.... fixing it, your last comment gave me a clear picture.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44174/discussion-between-ronny-linsener-and-t-mckeown)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that SUBSELECTs are less performant than JOINs?

Possibly. This depends entirely on the query in question. Many constructs that are frequently implemented with a subquery, which can just as easily be achieved with a join, are actually executed as a join internally by the query optimizer... in database systems with an enterprise grade query optimizer, like SQL Server and Oracle. MySQL's query optimizer is notably worse at these kinds of optimizations, you'd have to look into the `explain` output to see whether it is smart enough for your specific case or not. It could even decide not to apply this optimization even if it sees it, just because system load is sufficiently low that optimization would be slower than just executing the slower version.

Even if it is executed as a subquery, it depends on the query itself and the system load. A subquery **might** cause a quicker lock escalation, potentially causing table locks and thus slower execution in the case of more simultaneous queries on the same table. Without concurrency, extra locks don't cause noticeable extra slowdowns.

In general, try to use joins whenever possible instead of subqueries, but don't overdo it - subqueries usually perform perfectly fine and the query optimizer will do a good job of keeping the server alive. But also keep in mind that MySQL isn't exactly an 'enterprise grade RDBMS' and as such can be rather dumb in its optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

Switching this to a `join` without a subquery or aggregation is not obvious.

The idea is to do a `left outer join` *with* a condition on the `date_added` condition.  When this condition does *not* match, then you have the minimum:

```
SELECT categories_id, products_id
FROM  products_to_categories a left outer join
      products_to_categories b
      on a.products_id = b.products_id and
         b.date_added < a.date_added
WHERE b.date_added is null and a.categories_id != 0;
```

Comment: When I added the aliases your idea works. But i get more resultst, than my subselect.

Comment: I think that could occur if `date_added` were uniformly `NULL` for some products.

Comment: I need the MIN(date_added) because when there a more than two entries it would take the middle one and not the oldest.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, subqueries are more process-intensive because every query around the subquery needs to wait until that subquery is finished processing.  This is not necessarily the case with Joins.

Do you need help with the syntax of Joins?  Or was my answer all you needed?

Here's what you're looking for:

```
SELECT   a.categories_id,
         a.products_id
FROM     products_to_categories a
LEFT JOIN     products_to_categories b
  ON     a.products_id = b.products_id
WHERE    a.date_added = MIN(b.date_added)
  AND      a.categories_id != 0
GROUP BY a.products_id, a.categories_id
```

Comment: Yes,please I tried it with a `LEFT JOIN` on the same table but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can't have aggregate functions in a WHERE clause

Comment: Good catch!  Does @RonnyLinsener know this?  He'll want to take another look at his logic...

Answer (score -1):

```
Select products_to_catergoriesa.categories_id, 
products_to_catergoriesa.products_id, min(products_to_categories b.date_added)

from products_to_categories a
join products_to_categories b 
on products_to_categories b.products_id = products_to_categories a.product_id

where [table_name_here].catergory_id !=0
```